# Is $f,g$ increasing on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}$, $g(x)= \cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ which of the following are correct statements?

$1$. $f(x)\ge 0\forall x>0$

$2$. $g$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$

$3.$  $g$ is an decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$

$4$. $f$ is an decreasing function on $[0,\infty)$

$1$ True as $f'(x)=g(x)>0\forall x>0$ as $x\in(\frac{n\pi}{2},n\pi),n\in\mathbb{N}$   we have $\cos x\in (0,-1)$.

$2$ is true as By Taylor's Expansion of $\cos x$ near $0$ we get $\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$ so clearly $\cos x\ge1-\frac{x^2}{2}$

$3$ is False as $2$ Is true.

$4$. is false as $1$ is true.

Are my logics are correct?

Comment: Your answers are correct, your reasoning is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g''(x)=1-\cos x\ge 0$, the function $g'$ is increasing. But $g'(0)=0$. So, $g'$ is nonnegative on $[0,\infty)$, and $g$ is increasing there. Finally, use $f'=g$ to answer the questions about $f$.